# Is it safe to copy node_modules?

Tags: node.js

If I want to copy a node project: Does it make any difference if I just copy `node_modules` or install all the modules again from scratch via npm?

Comment: "This might void your warranty"

Comment: Most packages should copy fine. Where you might have issues is with copying [native addon](http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), that have to be compiled when installed, to a different system.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

#### 2017-05-12

I've updated this answer to reflect changes since the release of npm 3.x and new tools that are available.

[npm v3 dependency installation is now non-deterministic](https://docs.npmjs.com/how-npm-works/npm3-nondet) meaning you may get different packages depending on the order in which packages have been installed over time. This isn't necessarily a bad thing, just something to be aware of.

Given this change I personally *don't* copy my `node_modules` directory around too much (it's still possible though!) and instead opt for a clean install most of the time.

There are new tools like [Yarn Package Manager](https://yarnpkg.com/) which can speed up the installation process if you are doing that a lot (but as of 2017-05-12 it's unclear how well it handles private npm organisations and private scoped packages).

So the takeaway is still pretty much the same: it won't hurt, but maybe err on the side of a clean install. If something weird does happen and you run into problems then you can just delete `node_modules` and run `npm install`.

---

#### Original answer from 2014-06-08:

In general it should be fine - I copy the `node_modules` directory sometimes from my other projects to speed up the setup process.

You can always copy `node_modules` and then run `npm install` or `npm update` in the new project to make sure you've got up-to-date versions. npm will use the files in `node_modules` as a cache and should only bring down newer content if required.

In short: it won't hurt. If something weird does happen and you run into problems then you can just delete `node_modules` and run `npm install`.

Comment: My `node_modules` has a lot of `package.json` files which contain path information, such as `_args` and `_where`. What are those used for?  Are you sure they are ok, even if I move the `node_modules`?  Maybe it would be better to do a global search and replace to remove the paths, or set them to \unknown-path\.

Comment: I don't know what that metadata is used for. If you're concerned about it then it's probably not worth manually editing the files - just do a clean install instead :) npm is faster these days than it used to be and there are new options like [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/)

Answer (score 1):

### Linux command

To copy projects without node modules directory:

In the directory of your projects run this:

```
rsync -av --progress --exclude="node_modules" <source directory> <target directory>
```

for example:

```
rsync -av --progress --exclude="node_modules" . /mnt/d/omer/new-directory
```