# Installation of npm in every project created

Tags: node.js, dependencies

Every time I create a new project do I have to run ( `npm install`) for the *node_modules* folder and dependencies? Or could I just copy the *node_modules* folder from the previous project on my laptop?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it safe to copy node\_modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102022/is-it-safe-to-copy-node-modules)

Comment: The question is why would you do that ?

Answer (score 0):

If the dependencies of the projects are identical, then YES - you can copy the node_modules folder across projects.

However, in the project building setup, it is orthodox to run npm install in the target container or target directory.

---

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102072/4185234) answer for more opinion on this.

Answer (score 0):

You must run `npm install` to install the packages included in `package.json`. If these packages are exactly the same I think in theory you could just copy the node_modules folder but it should be highly recommended to run `npm isntall` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `npm install`, it faster and safer than copy many times, and each project maybe have different dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

yes you need to install node_modules node does not give you permission for each end every library or dependencies npm_install